# How can i get cover to create cover_db?

Tags: linux, perl, junit, jenkins, cover

Im trying to set up Jenkins to run tests and coverage on my Perl project. In Jenkins i have a shell script that looks like this:

```
perl --version
perl Build.PL
prove -v test.pl --timer -l t > jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-junit.TAP
/usr/local/bin/cover -test -report clover
```

When the shell is executes this call "/usr/local/bin/cover -test -report clover" it creates the following output :

```
Deleting database /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Banking/cover_db
cover: running ./Build test "--extra_compiler_flags=-O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-   coverage" "--extra_linker_flags=-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
test.pl .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=120,  7 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.91 cusr  0.04 csys =  1.00 CPU)
Result: PASS
Reading database from /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Banking/cover_db

Writing clover output file to '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Banking/cover_db/clover.xml'...
No such file or directory at /usr/local/share/perl5/Devel/Cover/Report/Clover/Builder.pm line 40.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

It seems to me like it deletes the cover_db directory if it exists but it cant recreate it, anyone knowing what im doing wrong ? As the Jenkins user i can both create and delete the cover_db directory so it should not be a user rights problem i guess.

Thank you in advance

Jan Eskilsson

Answer (score 0):

In the line (40) mentioned in Devel/Cover/Report/Clover/Builder.pm:

```
 open( my $fh, '>', $outfile ) or die($!);
```

With $outfile being 'clover.xml' in your example.

Edit: To clarify, it seems to me to die at

```
open ( my $fh, '>', '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Banking/cover_db/clover.xml' )
```

That is why I suspected one of the following problems, since 'open' itself has not yet failed me in any unrepdictable manner. I cannot, unfortunately, say exactly what the problem is. Hopefully someone can.

Thus, it should very likely be a problem with Clover not having access rights to write this file in the directory, as this line simply tries to open a file with write access and fails if open() fails.

Double check permissions for Clover, that should fix it.

Edit: since it is passing the whole path, ( i.e. $outfile seems to contain `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Banking/cover_db/clover.xml`, not just clover.xml, so it might also not have the directory created at that point, I did not delve deeply enough in the code to verify when that is done.

Thus, you may also want to check whether the directory exists at all after running, and whether it has rights to do so.

You can also check whether the directory exists or can be created by clover.

Comment: Hi bytepusher, thanks for your response. If i run cover as the jenkins user and cover_db exists it starts by deleting the cover_db directory and it never tries to create the cover_db directory again, at least it does not show any errors saying it cant create it. So i think thats the problem that cover of some reason never creates the directory again and I really cant understand why :-(

Comment: The error comes up when creating the report file, at least that is what the code looks like. Seems to me that it is not necessarily related to the cover_db file. The output does seem strange though: First it says it deleted, then it says it read. I was just trying to help out somewhat, I am not certain of the exact problem.